# AngularJS: How to filter data by comparing the search text to only certain members of JSON object?

Tags: html, json, angularjs

I want to filter a JSON based only certain members of the JSON object. Here is the [fiddler](http://jsfiddle.net/sachinbr/knp4fyqq/1/) and here is the html code.

```
<body ng-app="faq" ng-controller="faqDisplay">
   <input ng-model="searchText"></input>
   <div ng-repeat="question in questions|filter:searchText">
      <li>{{question.question}}</li>
   </div>
</body>
```

Here is the script for that

```
var faq = angular.module('faq', []);
faq.controller('faqDisplay', function ($scope) {
$scope.questions = [{
    question: "Abc",
    answer: "efg",
    count: "197",
    qname: "q1"
}, {
    question: "FGH",
    answer: "dfs",
    count: "61",
    qname: "q2"
}, {
    question: "IJK",
    answer: "dsds",
    count: "3241",
    qname: "q3"
}];
});
```

In my fiddle, if you enter in the values I have assigned for count or qname in the input field it will display the questions accordingly but I want it to filter only based on the data members: question and answer (Show the questions only if the searchText contains words/characters which are either in question or answer only).

Can anyone help me with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify the property you want to filter upon

```
filter:{question:searchText}
```

Here is the fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/knp4fyqq/2/

Here is full [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter)

If you want to search on multiple properties, easiest would be to call a function on controller for filter.

For example, create a function in controller like this

```
 $scope.search = function (row) {
        return (row.question.toLowerCase().indexOf($scope.searchText.toLowerCase() || '') !== -1 || row.answer.toLowerCase().indexOf($scope.searchText.toLowerCase() || '') !== -1);
    };
```

and update your filter in your binding like this

```
<body ng-app="faq" ng-controller="faqDisplay">
    <input ng-model="searchText"></input>
    <div ng-repeat="question in questions|filter:search">
        <li>{{question.question}}</li>
    </div>
</body>
```

And here is the fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/knp4fyqq/7/

Comment: I want to filter using two data members(i.e.,question and answer) not one